# Auto Update Date for Given range in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query by which I have to extract data from the server but every time I have to change the date range

`where date(usf.created_date) BETWEEN '2022-04-01 00:00:00' and '2022-04-30 23:59:59'`

but I want to get this range auto-update from today 30 days back.
I have tried the casting method `Cast(GETDATE() as smalldatetime)` but it shows an error in the same.

Comment: MySQL or (MS)sql-server? Please remove unrelated tags.

Comment: @Jens tag removed, and thanks

Comment: Now you removed both tags? Readd the tag for the dbms you use.

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL, and they vary a lot in their date/time functions. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming based on `GETDATE()` that this is SQL Server, you either want:

```
-- get everything going back exactly 30 days from this moment
WHERE usf.created_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE());
```

Or:

```
-- get everything going back 30 days from this morning at midnight
WHERE usf.created_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()));
```